Are questions on interaction with the conan.io people on-topic?
I have a package in the Conan C++ package management system. I've been having trouble getting the Conan people to notice/work on a new version of my package. I thought I might ask on SO for advice on how to make that happen, from people who have more experience with Conan. This would be a question about programming in the broad sense, but not in the narrow sense. Would it be in scope?

It is probably not in scope. My impression is that this would be similar to ask about, e.g., problems with the play store release process. I remember a duplicate for that, but I have to find it again.

Maybe: Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow? or Where would be a good place to ask questions about Play Store policy?

From your description, it feels less like the question would be able a programming or software development, and more about how to interact with a company that makes tools for programmers or software developers. That feels like it would be better on a forum dedicated to the company, or their product.

I've wondered about something vaguely similar. I'd been pondering what it would take to get compilers to communicate @flags arguments as build dependencies to buildsystems, not sure which component of the toolchain would be best to implement this at, and how to raise the question to the "right" parties (Ex. compiler vendors and buildsystem people). I ended up just raising a ticket on the CMake issue tracker. I don't have an answer to this meta question and I'm curious what others have to say about it.

" I thought I might ask on SO for advice" - yeah that's for Discussions or chat then. Advice is a very shaky foundation for a Q&A post, although you may have the experience to not fail at asking a Stack Overflow-compatible question under such circumstances. Since discussions is practically useless right now and chat is for large parts of the day pretty barren... probably ask somewhere else.

Ok, based on comments, I guess the answer is: No, it isn't.
I'll try to look for some sort of web forum for Conan business.
